# Range validation based on another property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently I have the model FooModel

```
public class FooModel
{
    [Range(0.001, 10000, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a decimal/number between {1} and {2}.")]
    [RangeValidator("BarMax")]
    public decimal? Bar { get; set; }

    public decimal BarMax { get; set; }
}
```

Following suggestions I created a custom range validator

```
public class RangeValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string dependentPropery;

    public RangeValidator(string dependentpropery)
        : base()
    {
        this.dependentPropery = dependentpropery;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.dependentPropery);
        if (property == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Unknown Property {0}", this.dependentPropery));
        }

        var value1 = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) as decimal?;
        if (!value1.HasValue)
        {
            return null;
        }

        decimal actualValue;

        if (value == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Value can not be empty.");
        }

        decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out actualValue);
        if (actualValue <= 0)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} Value can not be empty.", this.dependentPropery));
        }

        return actualValue > value1.Value ? new ValidationResult(string.Format("Value cannot exceed {0} {1}.", this.dependentPropery, value1.Value)) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to create you own custom validation attribute, or install an external library as @Slicksim suggested. There are plenty of question on SO on how to create custom validation, also working client side with jquery unobtrusive validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't in the range attribute, but you could add the [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) library.
Then you can set your range to be the max that your storage or primitive type will hold, then use foolproof's lessthan to constrain it to the BarMax property.